# Why does akismet prevent jetpack comments from appearing in my moderation queue?

Tags: comments, plugin-jetpack, moderation, akismet

On the blog I run, when I have Akismet activated, it somehow prevents comments posted via Jetpack from appearing in the moderation queue. I know it's Akismet because I have disabled every plugin but jetpack and received comments in the moderation queue successfully. When I have both jetpack and aksimet activated simultaneously, however, the comments do not appear in my moderation queue.